# Angular returning data as undefined from service

Tags: angular, angularfire

I'm trying to get the data from a subscribed variable from my user service via

userService

```
this.user$ = this.authService.user$;

this.user$.subscribe(user => {
  if (user) {
    this.currentUser = user;
  }
});
```

and my `user$` from the authServive

```
this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  switchMap(user => {
    if (user) {
      return this.afs.doc<any>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  })
);
```

and when I'm trying to get the data of currentUser in my settingComponent it worked perfectly by returning me the json file but when used in dashboard component its returning me undefined instead.

The steps I used were identical for both component and I'm not sure why one is returning me with undefined

on my dashboardComponent

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.isLoggedIn$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(map(user => !!user));
  this.isLoggedOut$ = this.isLoggedIn$.pipe(map(loggedIn => !loggedIn));
  //subscribe user observable from userService
  this.user$ = this.authService.user$;
  this.userPrivate$ = this.authService.userPrivate$;
  //subscribe user data from userService
  this.currentUser = this.userService.currentUser;
  this.currentUserPrivate = this.userService.currentUserPrivate;
  this.skillForm = this.fb.group({
    skill: ['',
      Validators.required
    ]
  });
  this.langForm = this.fb.group({
    language: ['',
      Validators.required
    ]
  });
  this.countryForm = this.fb.group({
    country: [this.currentUser.country,
      Validators.required
    ]
  });
  console.log (this.currentUser); //returns undefined
}
```

and so my coutryForm will not be able to fetch the user's country value as well

however with the same steps my settingComponent worked just fine in displaying the user's country

settingComponent

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.isLoggedIn$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(map(user => !!user));
  this.isLoggedOut$ = this.isLoggedIn$.pipe(map(loggedIn => !loggedIn));
  //subscribe user observable from userService
  this.user$ = this.authService.user$;
  this.userPrivate$ = this.authService.userPrivate$;
  //subscribe user data from userService
  this.currentUser = this.userService.currentUser;
  this.currentUserPrivate = this.userService.currentUserPrivate;
  this.viewProfile = this.userService.viewProfile;

  this.countryForm = this.fb.group({
    country: [this.currentUser.country.country,
      Validators.required
    ]
  });
  this.occupationForm = this.fb.group({
    occupation: [this.currentUser.occupation,
      Validators.required
    ]
  });
  console.log(this.currentUser); // returns user as json
}
```

And so i'm really confused at this situation right now

Comment: Pleas provide a working http://plnkr.co/ or https://stackblitz.com/ with at least part of the code so we can provide you some help.
Some things I am missing is the app.module.ts and full settingComponent and dashboardComponent so we can see that everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem with `switchMap`. It must return an `Observable`. In one of your cases you return simple `null`. Try to return `of(null)`.

```
this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  switchMap(user => {
    if (user) {
      return this.afs.doc<any>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
    } else {
      return of(null);
    }
  })
);
```